Airflow PostgresHook retrieval in dag
I'm using python to test the Airflow DAG. I have environmental variable:
AIRFLOW_CONN_DB="postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:6099/db"
and I use the following command to get the hook to get the hook:
hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="db")

Then I'm trying to read the table as dataframe:
sql='select * from "schema_name".user;'    
df = hook.get_pandas_df(sql)

but the output is the following:

psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1),
port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)   Is the server
running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections? connection to
server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection
refused (0x0000274D/10061)    Is the server running on that host and
accepting TCP/IP connections?

how to set connection as variable in a way such that I can use it as a hook then?

Looks to me like there is not a Postgres server running on the machine or if it is it is not listening on host localhost(127.0.0.1) and/or on port 5432.  Verify: 1) That the Postgres server is installed and running. 2) That the Connection settings in postgresql.conf are correct. I would also check to make sure you don't have more then one instance of Postgres installed/running.

@Adrian Klaver, but I need to connect to the 6099 port. Not default 5432. This is why I introduced variable with port 6099


6099 is not a 'normal' port number for Postgres, are you sure that is the Postgres server port? Can you connect directly using psql? 2) The error says you are picking up some other connection string that is trying to connect on port 5432. You need to track down where that is coming from.


@Adrian Klaver1) yes, the access to the db is OK, the problem appears via airflow connection 2) this is why I wrote this question - I do not understand from where 5432 appears. If it is default, why is it not overridden.

Is Airflow running in the same environment as where AIRFLOW_CONN_DB is being set?  Use os.eniron from here os to see what env variables are actually being seen by the Airflow code.

Variables (for example, I have AIRFLOW_VAR_TEMP_FOLDER) are taken from envs correctly, the problem is in the mentioned Connection (AIRFLOW_CONN_DB). The Connection itself is another Airflow entitiy, not the same as Variable and I can't get how to set it correctly


To be clear you do not see AIRFLOW_CONN_DB present in the instance of AIrflow you are running, correct? 2) Not sure what Variable is referring to?


I used Variables and Connections documentation to provide the Variables and configuration of Connections respectively

I reread the documentation. The problem was in typing postgresql (instead of postgres) and quotes inserted in url.
The correct env is AIRFLOW_CONN_DB=postgres://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:6099/db

should I delete the question?

It is acceptable to answer your own question and it helps the next person that runs into this issue.  Not sure why postgres instead of postgresql as the URI is usually shown as postgresql://[userspec@][hostspec][/dbname][?paramspec]. Well it works now so that is the important part.
